# execute script when ajax call complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 2 HTML select using jQuery multi-select cascade bind using ajax call it works fine the problem is I want to set value in master then bind detail then set value in detail but since it is ajax when try to set the value in detail the values not yet available.

Table Cars
CarID int
CarModel(Toyota)
CarSubModel(yaris)

```
 function GetCarData()
    {
        var CarID = getQuerystringByName('C');
        if (CarID!=null)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Query.asmx/GetCarByID",
                data: '{CarID: ' + CarID + '}',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (Result) {
                    Result = Result.d;
                    txtCarName.value = Result.CarName;
                    $("#ddlCarModel").val(Result.ModelID);
                      BindSubModel();// Ajax to load Sub Models
                      $("#ddlCarSubModel").val(Result.SubModelID);
```

I need to (some how) execute $("#ddlCarSubModel").val(Result.SubModelID);
after the sub ajax complete i do not want to use wait methods(Timers).

```
  function BindSubModel() {
        var ModelVal = $("#ddlCarModel").val();
        if (ModelVal != "") {
                $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Query.asmx/LoadCarSubModel",
            data: '{ModelID: ' + ModelVal + '}',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (Result) {
```

the web Method

```
     public class CarSubModelInfo
    {
        public int SubModelID { get; set; }
        public string SubModelName { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public List<CarSubModelInfo> LoadCarSubModel(string ModelID)
    {
        string Conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GPS_TrackingConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        CarSubModelInfo driver = new CarSubModelInfo();
        List<CarSubModelInfo> SubModelInformation = new List<CarSubModelInfo>();
        DataSet ds;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from T_SubCarModels where  ModelID=" + ModelID, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {

                    ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                }
            }
        }
        try
        {
            if (ds != null)
            {
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            SubModelInformation.Add(new CarSubModelInfo()
                            {
                                SubModelID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]),
                                SubModelName = dr["name"].ToString()
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return SubModelInformation;
    }
```

Comment: use `async:false` in ajax please find more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @Curiousdev I thought async is true by default?

Comment: @TobyMellor Thanxx.. i was in hurry while writing ;)

Comment: @Curiousdev Ah okay haha, async: false is also depreciated

Comment: @Curiousdev Please don't suggest `async:false` - even the *browser itself* recommends you don't do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: See duplicate.  2 options: Pass a call back to BindSubModel to call on success or, add a `return` in `BindSubModel` (ie `return $.ajax({...`) and use the promise `BindSubModel().done(function() { $("#ddlCarSubModel").val(Result.SubModelID); });`

Comment: @freedomn-m ohh that's great i didn't knew about dat thanxx.. :)

Comment: @Curiousdev here's a nice summary answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18957965/2181514

Answer (score 0):

Put `$("#ddlCarSubModel").val(Result.SubModelID);` 
Into success in the function `BindSubModel();`

Comment: Result is the success of the prev ajax it will not be available in  bindSubModel

Comment: send it there, as param BindSubModel(Result.SubModelID);

`    function BindSubModel(SubModelID) {
    ...
        success: function (Result) {
            $("#ddlCarSubModel").val(SubModelID);`